# Linq Where on FromSqlInterpolated when calling a table valued function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ef-core-3.1

I've got a table valued function called tf_ArtikelSearch, which takes a language code as input. I can execute it successfully as a SQL Query with

```
SELECT *
FROM tf_ArtikelSearch('D')
WHERE PackungId = 38673
```

Now I would like to use a Linq where to generate the same (or similar) query. But when I run below code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ArtikelSearchResult>> Search(ArtikelSearchFilter filter)
{
    var query = Set.FromSqlInterpolated($"dbo.tf_ArtikelSearch ({filter.SprachCode})")
                   .Where(result => result.PackungId == 38673);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitFromSql(FromSqlExpression fromSqlExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables.Query.AsOfQuerySqlGenerator.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.<VisitSelect>b__18_1(TableExpressionBase e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.GenerateList[T](IReadOnlyList`1 items, Action`1 generationAction, Action`1 joinAction)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.VisitSelect(SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.GetCommand(SelectExpression selectExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalCommandCache.GetRelationalCommand(IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Refdata.SAI.Data.Repositories.ArtikelSearchRepository.Search(ArtikelSearchFilter filter) in C:\dev\Refdata.SAI\Source\Refdata.SAI.Data\Repositories\ArtikelSearchRepository.cs:line 27
   at Refdata.SAI.Data.Tests.Integration.ArtikelSearchResultRepositoryTests.ArtikelSearch_OK_Test() in C:\dev\Refdata.SAI\Source\Refdata.SAI.Data.Tests.Integration\ArtikelSearchResultRepositoryTests.cs:line 21
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Note that the EF query works fine without the where clause.
Am I doing something wrong or is EF core 3.1 not capable of this?

Comment: Have you tried `$"SELECT * dbo.tf_ArtikelSearch ({filter.SprachCode})"`? LINQ can't know whether this is a function or stored procedure, hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SELECT * FROM` the same way you'd do in SQL, eg :

```
var query = Set.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.tf_ArtikelSearch ({filter.SprachCode})")
               .Where(result => result.PackungId == 38673);
```

Functions can't be called directly in a SQL query, so EF Core assumes you're trying to call a stored procedure which can't be composed in SQL.

This [doc example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data) shows just that case :

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Got to know the quirks. Thanks! The generated query is perfect.

Comment: @Philippe this is no different than any other ORM, or EF 6. Even there, you had to use some explicit extensions to tell EF6 that a specific object was actually a function, not a table. ORMs aren't the database itself and unless you tell them, they don't know what they are calling

Comment: @Philippe in real life, and big applications, the database is most certainly *not* an implementation detail